# Add button to list item in Ionic and AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to add a button in my Ionic app to add a list item which has a drop-down options in it. So far I have:

HTML:

```
  <div class="list" ng-repeat="option in options">
     <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="addOption()">
         Add
     </button>
     <label class="item item-input item-select">
        <div class="input-label">
            Name
        </div>
        <select>
            <option>Not interested</option>
            <option> Yes</option>
        </select>
     </label>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
  $scope.option = $localStorage;

    $scope.addOption = function() {
        $scope.option.push();
    };

  $scope.closeOption = function(index) {
        $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
  };
```

I know the above must be wrong but I cant see where? I am fairly new to angular JS

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the select menu so that there is one `option` for every option in the array.

```
<select>
  <option ng-repeat="x in option">{{x}}</option>
</select>
```

Also you are not specifying what is being added to `option`.

Comment: All i need to do is a list item

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the class as dropdown to display the options as list.

Comment: How would that be Keerti?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle?

Comment: I want to know the requirement, is it that add button should have the dropdown list?

Comment: there is add button which adds the dropdown list

Comment: I am not sure if I have understood it, when you click on add button what happens? where will the list get added? Is there another button that acts as dropdown?

Comment: There is a list item, with a dropdown list. Above that is a button where the users clicks and adds additional list items